# how to split a multidimensional array using key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to split the multidimensional array using the key..
here in this, I need to split the array by using the key (5) and split into separate arrays.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => i 
            [1] => FW 
        ), 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => was 
            [1] => VBD 
        ), 
    [2] => Array ( [
            0] => reading 
            [1] => VBG 
        ),
    [3] => Array ( 
            [0] => a 
            [1] => DT 
        ), 
    [4] => Array ( 
            [0] => book 
            [1] => NN 
        ), 
    [5] => Array ( 
            [0] => but 
            [1] => CC 

        ), 
    [6] => Array ( 
            [0] => she 
            [1] => PRP 
        ), 
    [7] => Array ( 
            [0] => was 
            [1] => VBD 

        ), 
    [8] => Array ( 
            [0] => writing 
            [1] => VBG 
    )
)
```

but i want result like this

```
array ( 
     [0] => Array ( [0] => i [1] => FW )
     [1] => Array ( [0] => was [1] => VBD )
     [2] => Array ( [0] => reading [1] => VBG ) 
     [3] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => DT ) 
     [4] => Array ( [0] => book [1] => NN )
)

array (
      [0] => Array ( [0] => she [1] => PRP ) 
      [7] => Array ( [0] => was [1] => VBD ) 
      [8] => Array ( [0] => writing [1] => VBG ) 
)
```

Comment: from your output 5 index is gone? why? any specific reason?

Comment: strange output, what's the benefit of such order `[0], [7], [8]`?

Comment: samuel are you sure you want that output? indexes are straing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO LINK](https://eval.in/600034)**

**php code:**

```
<?php

$key = 5;
$start_array = [
    ['i', 'FW'],
    ['was', 'VBD'],
    ['reading', 'VBG'],
    ['a', 'DT'],
    ['book', 'NN'],
    ['but', 'CC'],
    ['she', 'PRP'],
    ['was', 'VBD'],
];

$first = [];
$second = [];

foreach ($start_array as $start_array_key => $start_array_sub_array){
    if($key == $start_array_key ){

    }else{
        if($start_array_key<$key)
            $first[$start_array_key] = $start_array_sub_array;
        else
            $second[$start_array_key] = $start_array_sub_array;
    }

}
print_r($first);
echo "\n";
print_r($second);
```

**result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => i
            [1] => FW
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => was
            [1] => VBD
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => reading
            [1] => VBG
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => DT
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => book
            [1] => NN
        )

)

Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => she
            [1] => PRP
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => was
            [1] => VBD
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => writing
            [1] => VBG
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];

foreach($yourArray as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key < 5) {
        // If the key is lesser than 5, put it into the array 1
        $array1[$key] = $value;
    } elseif($key == 5) {
        // if it's 5, don't do anything
        continue;
    } else {
        // if it's greater than 5, put it into the array 2
        //if($key == 6){ $key = 0; }
        $array2[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `foreach loop` and use condition if `key` is less then 5 then create a `array` if greater then create another

```
   <?php
$data = array(array('a','b'),array('c','d'),array('e','f'),array('g','h'),array('i','j'),array('k','l'),array('m','n'),array('o','p'),array('q','r'));

foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    if($key < 5){
    $first[$key] =  $value;

    }else{
        if($key == 5)continue;
        else{
        $key = $key == 6 ? 0 : $key;// comment this line if you not want to change key 6 to 0   
        $second[$key] = $value;
    }}

}
?>
```

Replace `$data` with your array

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
$array1=array();
$array2=array();

for($x=0;$x<9;$x++){
    if($x<5){
        $array1[$x][0]=$cars[$x][0];
        $array1[$x][1]=$cars[$x][1];

    }
    else if($x>5){

        $array2[$x][0]=$cars[$x][0];
        $array2[$x][1]=$cars[$x][1];

    }

}

print_r($array1);
echo "\n";
print_r($array2);



?>
```